# Extention of Euclid's GCD Algorithm. (The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1, Edition 3, Section 1.2.1, Exercise 12)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, arithmetic, divisibility, irrational-numbers

Euclid's GCD algorithm which is used to find GCD of two input numbers, say, $c$ and $d$,
needs the inputs to be positive integers.

Exercise 12 provides an extension to this algorithm and allows $c$ & $d$ to accept 
values of the form $u+v\sqrt{2}$, where $u$ and $v$ are integers. 
In this case we can find a $r$ (of the form $u+v\sqrt{2}$) such that 
$c=dq+r$ , $q$ is a positive integer.
The algorithm can then continue as usual with $c$<-$d$ and $d$<-$r$ in the next step.

The algorithm will however not terminate if $c=1$ and $d=\sqrt{2}$ because there 
is no common divisor($q$) here.

However, the algorithm can be made to terminate in this case also if some extension 
is done to the divisor $q$, as explained here (by the author):

> If we extend the concept of divisor so that $u+v\sqrt{2}$ is said to divide $a(u+v\sqrt{2})$ 
>   if and only if $a$ has the form $u'+v'\sqrt{2}$ for integers $u'$ and $v'$, there 
>   is a way to extend the algorithm so that it always will terminate. If we have 
>   $c=u+v\sqrt{2}$ and $d=u'+v'\sqrt{2}$, compute $c/d=c(u'-v'\sqrt{2})/(u'^2-2v'^2)=x+y\sqrt{2}$
>   where x and y are rational. Now let $q=u''+v''\sqrt{2}$ where $u''$ and $v''$ are the 
>   nearest integers to $x$ and $y$; and let $r=c-qd$. If $r=u'''+v'''\sqrt{2}$, it follows 
>   that $|u'''^2-2v'''^2|<|u'^2-2v'^2|$, hence the computation will terminate.

I did not understand the last line that

> If $r=u'''+v'''\sqrt{2}$, it follows 
>   that $|u'''^2-2v'''^2|<|u'^2-2v'^2|$, hence the computation will terminate.

Please explain how $|u'''^2-2v'''^2|<|u'^2-2v'^2|$
 and how this proves that 
computation will terminate.

Comment: To learn more about euclidean quadratic number fields I recommend having on hand at least one *number theory* textbook. This is discussed in many classical textbooks, e.g. those by *Hardy & Wright, Harvey Cohn,* and *Harold Stark*, to name just a few of many elementary expositions.

Answer (score 0):

The computation should terminate because of the same reason as the usual Euclidean algorithm, in which we search the greatest common divisor of natural numbers $c$ and $d$ with $c>d$. Namely, we have $c=qd+r$ with $r<d$. If $r>0$ then we have $d=q’r+r’$ with $r’<r$ and so forth. Following this way we consecutively construct a sequence $b>r>r’>r’’>\dots$ of non-negative integer residues, which have to be finite and stop at the zero. In the question to this sequence corresponds a sequence $|b|>|r|>|r’|>\dots$, where $|u+\sqrt{2}|=|u^2-2v^2|$. When the sequence stops at $|r_k|=|u_k+\sqrt{2}v_k|$ we have $|u_k^2-2v_k^2|=0$. Since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, the equality can hold only if $u_k=v_k=0$.

Algebraically, the proposed algorithm extension is a part of a proof that a ring consisting of numbers of the form $u+\sqrt{2}v$ is a [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), endowed with a [Euclidean function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition) $|u^2-2v^2|$. In particular, that $|u'''^2-2v'''^2|<|u'^2-2v'^2|$ is proved in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1798621/71850) answer.