# Show that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right]$ is a Euclidean Domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ be a quadratic field with associated integer ring $$\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right] = \left\{a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$ and field norm $N$ defined by $N(a+b\sqrt{-3}) = a^2 + 3b^2$. Prove that $\mathcal{O}$ is a Euclidean Domain with respect to $N$. **Prove that every element of $F$ differs from an element of $\mathcal{O}$ by an element whose norm is at most $1/3$ (this is what I'm stuck on).**

Following almost the exact steps to this proof ([Proving that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a Euclidean domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150885/proving-that-mathbbz-sqrt2-is-a-euclidean-domain)) I write $a = \beta q + r$ and get that $N(r) < \left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 3 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right] *N(\beta) = 1*N(\beta)$, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get a bound of $1/3$ instead of $1$.

Comment: Suggestion: draw a picture of the lattice in theomplex plaine of points $a+ b\omega$ where $\omega = (1 + \sqrt{-3})/2$. Find a vertex near enough to the complex quotient.

Comment: See the **answer** at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23086